# What does this recondite quote by Hardy mean?

Tags: grammar

Check out this sentence:

> *Poetry is emotion put into measure. The emotion must come by nature, but the measure can be acquired by art.*

Is it saying "poetry is an emotion in a measure? Emotion will come from you naturally, and no need to labor for it. On the other hand, the measure comes only through work. You gotta work hard to get it?

Comment: I think that "[measure](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/measure)" was used in several senses: 1. "an action that is intended to achieve or deal with something"; 3. "a way of judging something"; 5. [music] [American] "any of the sections that a line of printed music is divided into, separated from each other by upright lines. The British word is bar."

Comment: I don't think *recondite* means what you think it means.

Comment: @StoneyB the title is quite right as it is. What am I missing? *recondite* an adjective means incomprehensible to an ordinary mind...isn't it?

Comment: @MaulikV No; it means expressing or drawing on hidden or esoteric knowledge, deliberately set beyond common understanding.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing particularly ‘recondite’ about this little epigram; the terms Hardy employs, *nature*, *art*, *measure*, are pretty ordinary. But you must take care when you consult your dictionary to look for definitions relevant to the discussion of poetry; and you must keep in mind that Hardy, as a poet, maintains different senses of his words in provocative and fertile tension.

Definitions from [Oxford Online Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us)
ART:

> **def 1:** The expression or application of human creative skill and imagination [...] producing works to be appreciated primarily for their beauty or emotional power.
>   **def 4:** A skill at doing a specified thing, typically one acquired through practice.

NATURE:

> **def 1:** The phenomena of the physical world collectively [...] as opposed to humans or human creations.
>   **def 2.1:** The innate or essential qualities or character of a person ...

MEASURE:

> *verb*, **def 2:** Consider (one’s words or actions) carefully.
>   *noun*, **def 4:** The rhythm of a piece of poetry or a piece of music.

Hardy's epigram alludes to critical questions which have been debated for centuries, sometimes millennia: Does a work of art ‘imitate nature’ or ‘transform nature’ or ‘create a second nature’?  Is the poet’s  ability an innate gift or an acquired skill? Should poetry employ a distinct diction and meter (‘measure’) or should it emulate the lexicon and rhythms of natural speech? Is poetry a spontaneous overflow of emotion into language or is it a contrived and disciplined—‘measured’—examination of emotion?

Hardy in effect dismisses the Either/Or debates and insists that poetry is Both/And. The poet **must** consult his ‘natural’ (that is, authentic) emotion as it is spontaneously expressed; but he must also shape a true recreation of that emotion through his acquired ‘artistic’ skill.

That’s a lot to pack into one short sentence, and I’ve barely scratched the surface. But that’s how poets think—and linguists.

Comment: So this "must" is the same as "we must all die" in the sense of inevitability?

Comment: by nature...from the day you were born? by art means through skill?

Comment: If you mean Hardy's *must come by nature*, he means the poet's moral obligation to examine his authentic emotion, as it derives from his own 'nature' without mediation by intellectual categories or social convention. But yes, Hardy also invokes the notion that one's 'nature' is the poetic gift he is born with. And when he speaks of *art* he means not only technical skill in deploying words but also the moral and ethical discipline which the poet undertakes in accepting his poetic vocation.

Comment: so my original interpretaion up there is half right?

Comment: @user4550 More than half, as far as it goes.